# How to search multiple keys in array and return value of first found?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multiple keys and an array where at a time one key will exist but i don't know which one exists.

My problem is I have to get value of that key which exist in array but i don't want to use `loop` or `isset` on individual key, I want to know is there any **builtin PHP Function** exist through which i can achieve this solution?

```
$keys = array("key1","key2","key3");
$data= array("mykey"=>"myval","mykey2"=>"myval2","key2"=>"key2val");

$val = isset($data["key1"])?1:(isset($data["key2"])?2:(isset($data["key3"])?3:0));//i dont want to use this or any loop
```

Comment: Why don't you want loops?

Comment: I don't think a function like that exists, but why do you not want to use a loop and isset to check if the key exists?

Comment: I don't want to use isset because in future my keys array will increase, I don't want to use loop because I want to keep my code shortest (as much as possible).

Comment: __Short__ does not mean __readable__.

Comment: If i will find any builtin function or way to achieve this then i will definately go for that, otherwise the final solution of looping exist though.

Comment: Jsust make a small function with 2 parameters ($keys and $data) where you do a `foreach` on $keys and do your logic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution :

```
 $keys = array("key1","key2","key3");
 $data= array("mykey"=>"myval","mykey2"=>"myval2","key2"=>"key2val");

print_r (current(array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($keys))));
```

I think you need to use loop, for that will be a better solution as

```
$keys = array("key1","key2","key3");
$data= array("mykey"=>"myval","mykey2"=>"myval2","key2"=>"key2val");

foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
  if(in_array($key,$keys))
  {
    // your logic
  }
}
```

Comment: to get output i needed to use current() function aswell in your first solution

Answer (score 2):

Take their intersection:

```
// Flip is needed for [key1 => 0, ...] representation
$list = array_intersect_key(array_flip($keys), $data);
// Check existence 
if ($list) {
    // You need the value, started from 1 (instead of zero)
    $val = 1 + current($list);
} else {
    $val = 0;
}
```

Comment: i couldnot understand adding of 1 in result

Comment: `isset($data["key1"])?1 :` - from your code, but after flip `key1` will have value `0`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner. But can you explain it after a month?

```
$keys = array("key1","key2","key3");
$data = array("mykey"=>"myval","mykey2"=>"myval2","key2"=>"key2val");

print_r( array_intersect($keys, array_keys($data)) );

// Output:
Array
(
    [1] => key2
)
```

Comment: to get output i needed to use current() function aswell in your solution

Comment: You should explain it so it still makes sense after a month. You will get an upvote for your troubles, especially if you take note of @imran Qamer's comment.